# How to set the scroll focus to specified control in c# windows app?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, scroll, focus

I have panel with the controls and scrolling .By default i set the focus to panel.(i need focus to panel by default)
if i scroll the panel to some where ,minimized the form and maximize it,it is setting the position to top of the form.
if i select the any of the control and do the same,it is focusing same control.

i think here the control focus is causing the problem.
how to set the control focus according to the scroll? or 
How to show the same scroll position when minimize and maximize the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sloved like this.

```
Point CurrentPoint; 

private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Math.Abs(this.AutoScrollPosition.X), Math.Abs(CurrentPoint.Y));
}

private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CurrentPoint = this.AutoScrollPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is Panel.ScrollControlIntoView what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want AutoScrolling off.

Create a new panel:

```
public class PanelEx : Panel
{
  protected override Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl)
  {
    return this.DisplayRectangle.Location;
  }
}
```